# Loading a section of JPEG2000 raster

Tags: python, raster, sentinel-2, rasterio, jpeg-2000

I have a raster band saved as a `.jp2` which I downloaded from Sentinel2-L2A. I can load it using rasterIO:

```py
with rasterio.open(path_to_jp2) as src:
    img = src.read(1)
```

This works fine, however, it takes a long time to load since the tile is big. I'm wondering if there's any way to load only a specific section of the image, let's say a small field stored as a geopandas dataframe which I extracted from a `.shp` file?

```py
field = geopandas.read_file(path_to_shp)
```

I was thinking about converting a `.jp2` into a cloud optimised geoTiff but I don't know if that would be the most efficient solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rasterio ["windowed" reading](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/windowed-rw.html):

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds

# Get the left, bottom, right, top vars from your shapefile
# assumes same CRS as your raster
with rasterio.open(path_to_jp2) as src:
    img = src.read(1, window=from_bounds(left, bottom, right, top, src.transform))
```